# What is the most efficient way to match elements of massive arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matching

Let me explain. Say, I have a massive array with more than 30 thousand elements and it tends to increase more in future. Now, I have an input and say I typed **whats_up**. Consider 3 elements out of 30 thousand with names **whats_up**, **hi_arcanadian_whats_up**, **hey_there_whats_up**. The output will be an array containing results for the match. So, what is the most efficient to do such match? I thought of doing something like this:

```
const arr = ['whats_up', 'hi_arcanadian_whats_up', 'hey_there_whats_up', 'hi', 'Do not choose me', ...] // Just test; real array is very very large
var main = []
for(var i in arr) {
  if(arr[i].includes("whats_up")) {
    main.push(arr[i])
  }
  i++
}
console.log(main)
// Output: whats_up,hi_arcanadian_whats_up,hey_there_whats_up
```

But it was a bad idea. It is really slow. So, is there any efficient way to do such things or it is just impractical? If not, how do I deal with such things? Everything is getting processed in back-end.

Comment: It's hard to build an index for a use case like that, and probably very memory intensive even if you could figure out a decent way to do it.

Comment: I assume you get the data from some kind of API or similar. If I were you, I would not returns such a huge array to be filtered on the fronted. I would delegate the task so that I get on the frontend only what is interesting to me. If it comes from a database, I would filter the data using the database. If it's something else, or the database is too slow, then maybe integrating with Elastic Search or some other search engine would work?

Comment: I am doing all kinds of things to the array in back-end indeed. Elasticsearch seems to be good for this scenario

Comment: Try using `for of` as `for in` in loops are for iterating objects rather than Arrays.  Also - i would use the inbuilt Array.filter() function unless you know that to be too slow.

The other thing to do if you are responding to a kepypress to run the filter is to debounce (search for that there will an answer) so you only run the search after the user stops typing.  I was able to get a similar operation working performantly on arrays of 100000

Comment: @Woody .filter() was insanely slow when I tested it. Actually the process is to be done in the back-end. The front-end provides the input to the back-end and then, it processes it